# How do I separate an array so it list out all the elements separated by commas except the last one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im on rails 4. I have an each block like this

```
blends.addons.each do |a|
....
end
```

Lets say I have a blend called "test" with three add-ons

I want to create a sentence in my blends show.html.erb that reads like this

> A test blend with vanilla, chocolate and cinnamon

My code to form this sentence would be something like

```
A <%= blend.name %> blend with <%= blend.addons.each do |a| %><%= a.name+", " %><% end %>
```

That code will just print out the names of all the addons attached to the blend separated by commas. How would I make my each block add commas up until the last element, then print "and #{the last element}"? Or is an each block not the best way to go about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is provided by an `ActiveSupport` method:

```
%w(Earth Wind Fire).to_sentence # => "Earth, Wind, and Fire"
```

You can configure it, [see doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-array-conversions)

In your case, I'd say:

```
%w(Earth Wind Fire).to_sentence(last_word_connector: ' and ')
# => "Earth, Wind and Fire"
```

Comment: Of course rails has a method to make this easy! Love it. Thanks.